# String is not saved correctly in database

Tags: php

I am trying to save a string in database and get something like this

> &#1055&#1077&#1088&#1080&#1086&#1076&#32&#1076&#10

The string that I want to save : `Период действия S...`

The table encoding is: `cp1251_general_ci`

I don't know in which encoding the string is - I am getting it from an excel document.

I tried this, but it didn' help.

```
$nomer = iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251', $str );
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: The string is definitely in cyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the database engine you're using, but try changing the table encoding to something like `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: I am using `cp1251_general_ci` and i can't change it , all system is working using this encoding.